# Typescript @Deprecated Interface ESLint

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm joining a new project and trying to properly migrate/deprecate towards camelCase, but the code base is complex so I don't want to insta-kill everything

```
interface foo {
  /**
   * @deprecated use 'propA' instead
  */
  prop_A: number,
  /**
   * @deprecated use 'propB' instead
  */
  prop_B: string
}

interface foo {
  propA: number,
  propB: string
}
```

My code, for the time being, has to set both props, but that's okay -- over time the legacy snake_case code can be remitted and we can start removing the duplicate setters

using the deprecation method is nice because ESLint strikes the legacy props (foo.<s>prop_A</s>) and shows a hover tip to use `foo.propA`

**My Question is**

Is there something like:

```
  /**
   * @deprecated use 'propB' instead
   * @quickfix 'propB'
  */
```

that will tell ESLint that there should be a quickfix and that on click I'd like to replace `prop_b` with `propB`?

Comment: snake  > camel 

Comment: I agree, but JS convention is camel :'(

Comment: conventions are for followers, i don't brake at red lights either